# Is there any difference between assigning the pointer to the function or passing its address as function argument?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I really don't know how to ask it more properly, but I will try to explain my problem.

Lets say we have the following:

```
int *ptr = foo(&ptr);
```

This for me I believe it means that, there is a `declaration` with `initialization` to the function `foo` with the pointer it self used as function argument.

Now the following:

```
int *ptr = foo();
```

I think is the same, but without any function argument, which means that, the function `foo` doesn't take any arguments.

Now lets take a look at the following two programs:

Program 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 3

int *foo(int **ptr);

int main(void){
    int *ptr = foo(&ptr);

    for (int i=0 ; i<SIZE ; i++){
        *(ptr + i) = i + 1;
    }

    for (int j=0 ; j<SIZE ; j++){
        printf("%d\n",*(ptr + j));
    }

    free(ptr);
}

int *foo(int **ptr){
    *ptr = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(*ptr));
    if(*ptr == NULL){
        printf("Error, malloc\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return *ptr;
}
```

Program 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 3

int *foo(void);

int main(void){
    int *ptr = foo();

    for (int i=0 ; i<SIZE ; i++){
        *(ptr + i) = i + 1;
    }

    for (int j=0 ; j<SIZE ; j++){
        printf("%d\n",*(ptr + j));
    }

    free(ptr);
}

int *foo(void){
    int *ptr = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(*ptr));

    if(ptr == NULL){
        printf("Error, malloc\ņ");
        exit(1);
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

What is the differences/benefits of `program 1` or `program 2`.

Is the pointer in the first or second program somehow different affected? Or is there any reason of using `program 1` or `program 2` ?

I'm asking, because the way how to program behaves looks that `program 1` and `program 2` are the same.

EDIT:
I know that the fist program has the pointer `ptr`  modified by the `foo` function and in the second one I declare it inside the Function `foo`, but this is not my Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only *practical* difference between the programs is that the first one could allocate double the amount of memory compared to the second.

In the first program you use `*ptr` to get the size, but `*ptr` is of type `int *` which on a 64-bit system is usually 64 bits. In the second program `*ptr` is an `int` and the size of an `int` is usually 32 bits on both 32 and 64 bit systems.

Since the first program *emulates* passing by reference, you could use it without using the returned pointer, and in fact it doesn't have to return a value at all and could be declared as returning `void`. Which one is preferred is a personal choice, I personally prefer the second alternative, but it also depends on use-case.

Comment: Thank you I just edited in the same time my Question.

Comment: Could you please elaborate where exactly does the first Program UB, because I was sure that is OK. This is a begginer Question btw :)

Comment: @Michi After rereading it's not really UB, it just allocates the wrong amount of memory (on a 64-bit system it will allocate double than what's needed): That's because `*ptr` is a *pointer* to an `int`, but in the second program `*ptr` is an `int`.

Comment: you could mention that `int *ptr = foo(&ptr);` should be replace by `int *ptr; foo(&ptr);` because as you pass the pointer adress to `foo()`, the pointer will be modified, and you then don't need to reaffect it

Comment: well i this particular case it's at least redudant as in foo you already modified ptr, then you reassign this modified ptr to ptr

Comment: @Guiroux You right. I deleted my comment because i noticed that now :). But the comment of davmac is different,

Answer (score 2):

In first program, you alloc `SIZE * sizeof(int *)` bytes, and use that memory as if it was `SIZE * sizeof(int)` long. That means that if you had `sizeof(int *)` < `sizeof(int)` you would run in a buffer overflow.

Another problem is that in `int *ptr = foo(&ptr);` you are modifying the variable `ptr` twice in one single expression, which is bad because you cannot know which one occurs first. But as you normally write same value it should be ok here.

Another difference is that in first program, you set the value of `ptr` to NULL in case of allocation error before calling `exit()`, while in the second, the variable remains uninitialized. But as you use exit in that case, the ptr variable immediately vanishes and could not be used even in an `atexit` registered function.

IMHO provided you fix first program by using `*ptr = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));` or  `*ptr = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(**ptr));`, the 2 versions behave the same.

Comment: "which is bad because you cannot know which one occurs first" - yes you can, in this instance. The function call must complete before the assignment is evaluated.

Comment: @SergeBallesta This means that, this `malloc(SIZE * sizeof(*ptr));` should be `malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));` ?

Comment: @Michi: If you want to allocate memory for SIZE ints, yes.

Comment: @SergeBallesta OK, anyway the main Question is hard to Answer because after I read my Post i realize now that it is different from what i meant. I only needed to know if using the first program does the same thing as the second program. :)